# Elasticsearch Highlighting not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying exact match on numbers using the query :

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":24,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "query":"+\"423.0\"",
                  "fields":[],
                  "boost":"50"
               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match":1,
         "filter":[
            {
               "terms":{
                  "FOLDER_ID.keyword":[ 2, 8, 9, 12, -1 ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "highlight":{
      "type":"unified",
      "fields":{
         "*":{

         }
      }
   }
}
```

Highlighting is not working as required. It is highlighting random results.
Like:

```
"highlight":{
   "Value1":[
      "<em>0</em>"
   ],
   "Value2.keyword":[
      "<em>423.0</em>"
   ],
   "value3":[
      "<em>D:\\Ser\\tim\\tim\\FileSystem\\acred\\temp\\1541662854708</em>"
   ],
   "value4":[
      "<em>0</em>"
   ],
   "term":[
      "<em>0.0</em>"
   ]
}
```

My analyzers at index and search time are: 
My search analyzer is different from my index analyzer
I have used patter capture at index analyzer and set it to false at search analyzer. Will this analyzer at search time affect my exact match query?

```
"analysis":{  
   "filter":{  
      "indexFilter":{  
         "type":"pattern_capture",
         "preserve_original":true,
         "patterns":[  
            "([@,$,%,&,!,.,#,^,*]+)",
            "([-]+)",
            "(\\w+)"
         ]
      },
      "searchFilter":{  
         "type":"pattern_capture",
         "preserve_original":false,
         "patterns":[  
            "([\\w,-]+)"
         ]
      }
   },
   "analyzer":{  
      "indexAnalyzed":{  
         "filter":[  
            "indexFilter",
            "lowercase"
         ],
         "tokenizer":"whitespace"
      },
      "searchAnalyzed":{  
         "tokenizer":"whitespace",
         "filter":[  
            "searchFilter",
            "lowercase"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a sample document along with the mapping in the question w.r.t the query. I've tried in my machine and the query you've mentioned works as expected. Also which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I have used custom analyzers at both search and index time. This is probably affecting this case. Can I provide a search analyzer at query time?

Comment: I am using Elasticsearch 6.3.2

Comment: It is always preferred to have same `analyzer` used during `search` and `indexing` time. You can try by adding `"analyzer": "<your_desired_analyzer>"` next to `boost` in the above query and see how it goes. Meanwhile I'll try at my end.

Comment: @Kamal , could you share the official es docs which says `preferred to have same analyzer used during search and indexing`.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have used `preferred` there but `usually`. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-analyzer.html
The entire point being, during both analysis phase, we are going to create tokens and search tokens in inverted indexes. There are possibilities we may not be able to search tokens if analyzers applied are different at both times